# Same font is rendered differently in IntelliJ IDEA vs. Android Studio

Tags: java, fonts, android-studio, intellij

I use both IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio for development, and for the longest time I've been trying to figure out why the two programs, *from the same company*, and *built on the same codebase*, and using the *exact* same font settings (and same text anti-aliasing method) will render the text in the editor pane differently.

For example, with both programs set to use `DejaVu Sans Mono, 12pt`:

- Android Studio:

  [image]
- IntelliJ IDEA:

  [image]

You can clearly see the difference, the font is thinner and/or  almost like it isn't anti-aliased in IntelliJ.

This has been driving me up the wall, as I find the text in IntelliJ much harder on the eyes.

**Has anybody else experienced this before and know how to fix it?**

Comment: I don't see the difference personally. Granted after decades of staring at a computer screen, my vision may be less than optimal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I managed to figure out how to fix it, and it's definitely not what I would have expected.

Turns out that IntelliJ was using my system JDK (Oracle's JDK 8) while Android Studio, which is now bundled with a JDK, was using its bundled one (OpenJDK 8).

Simply telling IntelliJ to use Android Studio's bundled JDK instead of the system JDK fixed the issue. You can do that like so:

1. Go Help --> Find Action

   [image]
2. Search for "boot JDK"

   [image]
3. Click the `...` in the drop down menu

   [image]
4. Point it to `{AS install DIR}/jre`

   [image]
5. Tell IntelliJ it's OK to restart:

   [image]
6. When it comes back up, the font will now be fixed!

Comment: Very useful answer - solved my issue with rendering.

Comment: Note that this solution is pretty out-dated now.

Comment: @Yar what is the new solution?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Edit `<JetBrains product directory>/jre/jre/lib/fontsfont.conf`

2 - Comment out all the `<test>` sections

Resulting file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
<!--
    <test name="family" qual="all" compare="not_eq">
      <string>Consolas</string>
    </test>
    <test name="family" qual="all" compare="not_eq">
      <string>Noto Sans Mono CJK JP</string>
    </test>
    <test name="size" qual="any" compare="less">
      <double>12</double>
    </test>
    <test name="weight" compare="less">
      <const>medium</const>
    </test>
-->
    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
      <const>hintslight</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

3 - Restart Idea

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this too. I am using the One Dark theme on IntelliJ and Android Studio. IntelliJ by default shows colors more vividly it seems.

If you choose Theme > One Dark in IntellJ, and Theme > One Dark Vivid in Android Studio then the differences are less apparent.